# what is the difference between 'http.Client' and '&http.Client' in go version 1.12

Tags: go

I'm creating a http request by 'net/http', the [official document](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) use `&http.Client{}`, but I try to delete `&` can run normally.

```golang
client := &http.Client{}
```

```golang
client := http.Client{}
```

What is the difference between two way? The best practices is?

Comment: visit the go-tour to get a refresher on pointers vs. values: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Comment: Sometimes the compiler is helping you with defining the pointer. So maybe both can work.

Answer (score 1):

> The best practices is?

The best practice is to learn the fundamental concept of the language. Here values and pointers. A starting point is https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1 (or better the whole Tour).

It is of little value to memorize whether to use &http.Client{} or http.Client{}.

And if in doubt: Just peek at the standard library, e.g. with `go doc -src net/http.DefaultClient`.